# Expression.Body.Expressions -- how to use it?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

This is what I can see in the QuickView window:
[image]
I want to use the Expressions property in my code, but it is not accessible:
[image]
Does anyone know how to use this Expressions property in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *compile-time type* of `expression.Body` is `Expression`.  No such property exists.

The *runtime type* of `expression.Body` appears to be a `NewArrayInitExpression`.  That type has the `Expressions` property that you're looking for.

You need to cast it to the appropriate type to be able to access the appropriate property.  The closest accessible type is `NewArrayExpression`.

```
var expressions = ((NewArrayExpression)expression.Body).Expressions;
```